# console.log() show that element exists but says it's undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I'm trying to retrieve some data from an object. I do `console.log(my_obj)` and get something like this:

[image: console]

`Graphic` section looks like:

[image: graphic]

I'm looking for an object graphic. But when I do `console.log(my_obj.graphic)` it says

> undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: may be when you log the object it does not exists but is updated later... can you log `console.log(JSON.stringify(my_obj))`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank for input. Adding your code I got `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: What is the typeof `s` in the graphic?

Comment: @Jai That also was my question) Can't find any refference that explain this. BUT! Firefox says that this is also an `Object`

Comment: @Steve.B do you get any response if you try something like ```console.log(my_obj.graphic.added)``` or is that still undefined?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Thanks for input. Now I'm getting `Cannot read property 'added' of undefined`

Comment: @Steve.B you may have to show some code. it actually isn't undefined so there is something wrong with your code. do you log at exactly the same place in your code?

Comment: @B.Kemmer Yes, I'm agree with you. I guess I retrieve my object in a wrong way. What I actually trying to do is get the coordinates of highcharts pie point on a chart. But those I have to ask another question.